# What is the Update URL for Dynamic DNS for Google Domains

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns, google-domains

Google Domains supports Dynamic DNS. That is great since my domain and Dynamic DNS information can come from the same provider.

For Dynamic DNS to work, I usually need the following info:

- Update URL
- Hostname
- Username
- Password

Of the four variables above, I know three. From Google, I can get *Username* and *Password*. I also know my server's *hostname*. However, I do not know the *Update URL*. In other words, I do not know to which Google server I should send the information to in order to update my IP Address.

Which Google Domains server should I notify about my IP Address change?

Comment: Checking the API [here](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en) for Google Domains, it looks like: `https://domains.google.com/nic/update`. If you're not using a client to perform the update, then check the API docs on the format to make the request.

Comment: @dan, Hi.. You gave me great starting point. From that one i could start experimenting. The real Update URL is: https://domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=www.domainame.url. You you wish, you can retype this comment as answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Done, with more details to make it clearer for others too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Dynamic DNS docs for Google Domains, under the section for their [API](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en) (near the bottom), the base *Update URL* is:

```
https://domains.google.com/nic/update
```

The format for this URL to submit a *POST request* (GET is also allowed) for your Google domain is:

```
https://username:password@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=subdomain.yourdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4
```

Where your `hostname` would equal your Google domain, including `www` or other subdomain you're redirecting, and `myip` equaling the IP address of where to update the redirection to.

For additional information, see [Google Domains: Dynamic DNS](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en)

Comment: At the end, ```&myip=1.2.3.4``` should be, and appears to be optional.  If left out, the public IP that the server sees the request coming from should be used to update the dynamic DNS record.  

--- Just tested, appears to work just fine, same as the previous service I used which was also dyndns2 compatible.  (That was dns.he.net if anyone feels like checking out another free bring-your-own-domain dns service.)